# How can I calculate the degree of nodes in D3 v5?

Tags: d3.js

I am learning D3 and trying to scale the radius of nodes based on its degree in D3 v5. My code is like

```
 nodes.forEach(function(d){
        d.degree=0;});
links.forEach(function(d){
        nodes[d.source].degree += 1;
        nodes[d.target].degree += 1;});
```

It returns error that

```
Uncaught TypeError: nodes.forEach is not a function
```

Anyone can provide a good solution?

Comment: What do you get if logging `nodes` immediately before you attempt to use `nodes.forEach`?

Comment: It returns the contents of nodes (nodes={})

Comment: forEach is not a method of objects, it is a method of arrays - and it appears that `nodes` is not an array but an object instead.

Comment: I am not restricted to use forEach. My goal is to calculate the degree of nodes. Do you know any methods I can use in d3 v5?

Answer (score 5):

Something like this will work for d3.js V5:

```
// Add degree 
d3.selectAll('g.node')
  .each(function(d) {
    d.degree = 0;
  });

// Calculate degree
links.forEach(function(d){
    d.source.degree += 1;
    d.target.degree += 1;
  });

// Accessor functions to get min & max
var minDegree = d3.min(
  d3.values(nodes), function(d) {
    return d.degree; })

var maxDegree = d3.max(
  d3.values(nodes), function(d) { 
    return d.degree; })

// Create node scale based on degree
var nodescale = d3.scaleSqrt()
  .domain( [minDegree, maxDegree] )
  .range( [3, 15] ); // Change this to your desired range

// Add the node circles
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return nodescale(d.degree);
    })
```